# How to delete Shopify Webhooks made thru Shopify API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, webhooks

I'm having trouble deleting Webhooks that I created thru the Shopify API.
To create the webhook, I used this code in RoR:

```
webhook = ShopifyAPI::Webhook.create(format: "json", topic: "orders/create", address: "some address")
```

I'm able to send a GET request and retrieve all the webhooks that were created. But when I send the DELETE request with the respective ID, the response is "404 Not Found - errors: Not found".
I'm sending the DELETE request using Firefox's RESTClient, and the format is like this:

```
DELETE https://api_key:shared-secret@hostname/admin/webhooks/1855159.json
```

Maybe it's not working because the webhooks were created via the API. Is there another way to delete the webhooks?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

DELETE/admin/webhooks/4759306.json

Delete a webhook

Remove an existing webhook from a shop

```
DELETE /admin/webhooks/#{id}.json
```

Answer (score 2):

I think when you remove the app from admin panel, the webhooks created by that app are automatically removed

Comment: Yes, you're right. And how can you delete a specific webhook?

Answer (score 2):

That is how you delete a webhook created by your application. Webhook `1855159` was created by the shop and not created by an application and can only be deleted by the shop's admin.

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve your webhooks first and then delete them.

```
@webhooks = ShopifyAPI::Webhook.find(:all, :params => {:limit => 10})
@webhooks.each {|webhook| webhook.destroy }
```