# ShopifyAPI Webhook Removal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I have checked the following URLs:

[How to delete Shopify Webhooks made thru Shopify API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267547/how-to-delete-shopify-webhooks-made-thru-shopify-api?rq=1)

[Deleting Webhooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747299/deleting-webhooks?rq=1)

But neither seem to really explain how to remove them via inside an app.

I have for example over 100 stores with legacy webhooks that I want to remove for them using the API.

```
@legacyhooks = ShopifyAPI::Webhook.find(:all, :params => {:limit => 15, :created_at_max => '2013-09-02', :order => "created_at DESC" })
```

Which this works great. But How do remove them?

I have tried:

```
ShopifyAPI::Webhook.destroy  ShopifyAPI::Webhook.delete  ShopifyAPI::Webhook.remove
```

And none of those seem to work.

**EDIT:**
I have tried: `ShopifyAPI::Webhook.delete({ :id => h.id })`

Where the PKID h.id is within a loop. But I get a 404 error.

There is documentation for `ShopifyAPI::Webhook.create` and `ShopifyAPI::Webhook.find` but after that, nothing.

I DO NOT wish use the CLI or run a cURL command for each one (eg. could be thousands)

I just want to do it automatically within the app that created it itself.

Answer (score 6):

Simple. Try this. Works perfect for me every time...

```
@legacyhooks = ShopifyAPI::Webhook.find(:all, :params => {:limit => 15, :created_at_max => '2013-09-02', :order => "created_at DESC" })
@legacyhooks.each {|wh| wh.destroy }
```

You can go crazy extending this concept...

For example.. one of my rake tasks... is:

```
def remove_webhooks
  ShopifyAPI::Webhook.all.each {|wh| wh.destroy if wh.topic == 'products/update'}
end
```

'Nuff said?